# Handling nulls in nested object maps with JQ

Tags: json, null, jq

I'm just learning jq, and a bit stumped here.  Suppose I've got a file entitled `testcite.json` like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "JoeSchmoe2020",
    "abstract": "Here's some junk",
    "author": [
      {
        "family": "Scmoe",
        "given": "Joe"
      },
      {
        "family": "Smith",
        "given": "Sally"
      }
    ],
    "title": "I wrote words!"
  },
  {
    "id": "EdithJones2020",
    "abstract": "It's an abstract",
    "author": [
      {
        "family": "Jones",
        "given": "Edith"
      },
      {
        "family": "Wilson",
        "given": "Eric"
      }
    ],
    "title": "These are more words!"
  }
]
```

and suppose what I want to convert it to is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "author": [
      "Scmoe",
      "Smith"
    ],
    "title": "I wrote words!"
  },
  {
    "author": [
      "Jones",
      "Wilson"
    ],
    "title": "These are more words!"
  }
]
```

The following command works to get me what I want... so long as there aren't any nulls.

```
cat testcite.json | jq '[.[] | {author: .author | map(.family), title}]'
```

But the moment there's a null, this blows up.  Suppose I change my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": "JoeSchmoe2020",
    "abstract": "Here's some junk",
    "author": [
      {
        "family": "Scmoe",
        "given": "Joe"
      },
      {
        "family": "Smith",
        "given": "Sally"
      }
    ],
    "title": "I wrote words!"
  },
  {
    "id": "EdithJones2020",
    "abstract": "It's an abstract",
    "author": null,
    "title": "These are more words!"
  }
]
```

then when I run the same command, what I would expect to get would be something like

```
[
  {
    "author": [
      "Scmoe",
      "Smith"
    ],
    "title": "I wrote words!"
  },
  {
    "author": [],
    "title": "These are more words!"
  }
]
```

(I'd also be happy with a null in place of the empty list).

Unfortunately, instead, I get the error:

`jq: error (at <stdin>:23): Cannot iterate over null (null)`

I've tried scattering in question marks:

`cat testcite.json | jq '[.[] | {author: .author | map(.family?), title}]'` just produces the same error.

`cat testcite.json | jq '[.[] | {author: .author | map(.family)?, title}]'` produces a syntax error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
[.[] | {author: .author | map(.family)?, title}]
jq: 1 compile error
```

Is there any way I can get the value extraction to just handle nulls sensibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward solution would be to test for `null`, e.g.

```
[.[]
 | {author, title}
 | .author |= if . then map(.family) else [] end
]
```

or similarly:

```
map({author: (.author 
              | if type == "array" 
                then map(.family) 
                else [] end),
     title} )
```

Comment: Thank you!  weirdly, I also discovered that a totally alternate format works without having to explicitly test for null: `cat badcite.json | jq '[.[] | {author: [.author[]?.family], title}]'`

Comment: Not weird, just not quite as straightforward.